# How to group nodes in Sverchok?

Tags: node-editor, add-on, groups, sverchok

From node tree type, I can easily group nodes by easily add Frame (layout>frame). However I use Sverchok add one in which there is no such layout like node tree type at all.

Comment: @magarijn - It's a beta feature, if you have problems please contact the [sverchok github issue tracker](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues).

Answer (score 6):

Select the nodes you want to group and click **Create a node group** .
To put nodes in a frame select them then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> .

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just to update this question, in Sverchok, Grouping see "Monads".
https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/pull/809

Lots of useful information at GitHub thread. Copy and paste from Sverchok Github pull request:

> ## "Group Nodes"
>
> *codename: Monads*
>
> Similar to Blender's Shader Trees, Sverchok now how as its own implementation of Group Nodes and we use the same keyboard short cuts.
>
> shortcut   behaviour
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>  Group selected nodes (relink to peripheral nodes)
> - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>    Group selected nodes, but don't link peripherals
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> Un-group the active Group Node
> - <kbd>Tab</kbd>    Enter or exit group
>
> Group Nodes have not been tested by many people yet, and that is why we are presenting it to you to help us break it in new and unpredictable ways. We expect that many eyes will help us make the feature more robust. Please use the issue tracker to send us questions / bug reports.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Automatic socket creation by dragging noodles to the Input / Output nodes.
> - The Tool Panel lets you Delete/Rename/Move/Recast (to different socket type) sockets
> - Old beta groups are automatically updated
> - Append works
> - Link mostly works

#### Known issues

Known issues are fluid and should be checked on the [remaining issues thread](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/803) on the issuetracker