# Cloning objects to multiple locations in Sverchok

Tags: sverchok

The attached set up works fine, but visually it's a mess, and I can't help wondering if there's a much simpler way of expressing this idea...

[image]

Objects A, B, C, and D are all clones of rotated cylinder M. A and C are slightly scaled down versions of M, and B and D are slightly scaled up.

Further, A and B share a fixed Y-axis, and C and D share a variable Y-axis.
A and D share a common X-axis, as do B and C. Theses axes are equidistant from x=0. Yep, they're the vertices of an imaginary rectangle, with side A-B centred on 0,0.

This is what my set up for this presently looks like:

[image]

Can this be simplified?

[image]

Comment: For me, this doesn't look that complicated for a node setup. It could use a few "reroute" nodes but given what you are trying to achieve I would say it is pretty dense already. I don't know much about sverchok but maybe you can add a "group" similar to shader nodes for the 4 "Move" nodes on the right since they all do the same things with different parameters ?

Comment: @Gorgious "I don't know much about sverchok" - you and me both!!... Thanks

Comment: May be relevant https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29226/how-to-group-nodes-in-sverchok

Comment: this isn't massively complicated. i'm afraid it's partially my fault for not providing a way to colour individual objects inside a single ViewerDraw. Otherwise you would be able to use one VD and pass it the matrices/colours. Sometimes complex ideas can be described in few nodes, other times simple ideas require more nodes than seems right, and there's a whole gradient inbetween. I may still add a color socket to VD.

Comment: @zeffii Did you mean to comment on this thread? The colours aren't the problem, and this tool of yours is brilliant, so I can't see that any of it is YOUR fault!!!

Comment: yes, that comment is totally intentional. but if the cylinders don't need to be coloured (useful when you're starting out... but lateron less useful), then kabu offers a nice approach below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.

[image]

This is possibly the easiest you can go. Duplicate with a matrix in, and alter attributes individually with a list input.
By changing the list input length, you add and remove objects.
Changing their attrs individually as you please you can tamper with their pos,scale,rot.

A couple of notes. You don't need "Move"; LOL, that not an object move, it's a vector move. I know, the name is tricky! It moves all the "points" of your object in some direction. Basicly it's a vector push.
You don't need a rotation node, as you can see matrix in it's all you need.

[The blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RGrm_sb1xZyP1BHe99_w18Zr_bNc2l6q)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works now, and is I think more manageable than what I had before. The final part of the puzzle requires unioning the smaller cylinders with (and subtracting the larger cylinders from) a larger solid. I do this by baking everything and then performing a couple of Boolean operations in Blender, but it would be nice to keep everything in Sverchok, such that all the end user had to do was select a 'Length' and a 'Height' and export.

Comment: Fine. Lastly, you could have a try at CSG Boolean Mk2, if you need a boolean node. Mind, last time I tried it I found to be buggy (about 2 years ago). Do not expect miracles.

Comment: I have tried that, but (of course) it's actually a bit more complicated than that; I'll play around a bit more and maybe post a dedicated question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by some examples elsewhere, here's my best attempt so far, but it doesn't (yet?) solve the problem of setting A and C to a different scale from B and D...[image]

[image]

...but as far as it goes, it looks a bit tidier.

EDIT:

Right, so, with Kabu's help, the inclusion of a 'simple?' List Input has solved the next part of the puzzle. Very neat - although Kabu has suggested that there is room for further optimisation as consequence of redundancy!!

[image](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/JoWGSlO7/)

Answer (score 2):

Really you have *no* need to simplify this node setup. As you have done so far, you have pretty much simplified it as much as you **want**. You actually do not want the nodes to be *too* simple, or else you actually will have problems with controlling things later. 
If I were you, I would keep the node setup you have currently, and work off of there. Unless your computer is very low on RAM, or has a slow processor, you honestly have no reason to simplify further.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the vote of confidence; as a novice, I just thought I might be missing something.